# $-\iint_{A}(y+x)\,dA$ Evaluating

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am bit unsure about the following problem:

Evaluate the double integral:

$$-\iint_{A}(y+x)\,dA$$

over the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,1), (2,0)$

OK, so I figured here that I would do this by first evaluating the integral over the region bounded by the vertices $(0,0), (1,1), (1,0)$ and then evaluate the integral over the region bounded by the vertices $(1,0), (1,1), (2,0)$ before adding the two answers together, and then reversing the sign of this answer (since there is a minus sign in front of the original double integral).  Thus, I begin by finding:

$$\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{x}(y+x)\,dy$$

When solved this gives me the answer $\frac{1}{2}$.

Next I solve:

$$\int_{1}^{2}dx \int_{1}^{2-x}(y+x)\,dy$$

When solved this gives me the answer $-\frac{7}{6}$.

I have verified both the integrals in Wolframalpha, and they give me the same answer.  I would therefore believe that the final answer should be:

$$-(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{7}{6}) = \frac{2}{3}$$

However, the final answer should, according to the book, be $-\frac{4}{3}$.

Thus, obviously I do something wrong here.  If anyone can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.  Is it perhaps that it is not allowed to "split up" this into two separate integrals?  I couldn't find a way to solve this without doing this.

Comment: I see one problem at least: The inner ($y$) integral in the second part should start at $0$. Anyway, you can avoid the splitting by doing the integrals with the $x$ integral on the inside. Try it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But why should the second integral start at 0?  The y-values being at 1 and end up at 0 (hence I chose y = 2-x for the upper value of the integral).

Comment: Draw a picture. The whole triangle has its base at the $x$-axis, and so does each of the two pieces resulting from the split.

Comment: You can also solve this with the Gauss integral theorem on $F(x,y) = xy$ and evaluate the integral on the boundary instead.  Maybe this is easier, since the boundary is made of line segments.

Comment: It seems you may be confusing the two bounds. The bound that begins at $1$ and ends up at $0$ is the upper bound; the lower one is $0$ throughout. Also, you can tell from the sign that $-\frac76$ must be wrong, since the integrand is non-negative throughout the triangle.

Comment: Ah, now I get it!  Duh.  Of course - the y lower bound is zero throughout.  Thanks a lot all of you :).  I just needed to get my head straight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second integral should be $$\int_{1}^{2}dx \int_{0}^{2-x}(y+x)dy.$$
Your lower $y$ limit was 1 instead of 0.

Draw the triangle to see the area you are integrating over.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I just figured it out.  Stupid mistake on my part :).